# How to close Androidwear app using Mobile

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have a basic media player app that works on android wear. I want to close wear app when user closes my app on mobile side? How can I do that? I have used too much time and couldn't find anything. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a `PutDataRequest` to send a `DataEvent` to your Wear app asking it to finish itself. Then, on your Wear app, just finish it when you receive this event.

Answer (score 1):

**Phone side:**
I assume you already are communicating with the wear device via GoogleApiClient (Wearable.API). If you are, you can use the MessengeApi to send a custom message across to your Wear app. (Just remember to add capabilites for both.) Easy directions are [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#SendMessage).

**Wear side:**
Just implement the MessageListener interface in your main activity. When the message comes in via onMessageReceived(), you can call finish(). Easy directions are [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#ReceiveMessage).

Finally, there is a Google Android Wear [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer) for the DataLayer. This covers sending Messages with other stuff if you want to dig into it.